# Laravel Fetch Value form Session

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Here is my Session and i would like to fetch the value from Sample_table  to get the  **original** array value how can i do that ?

{{ dd(Session::get('sample')[0]) }}

```
 Sample_table{#266 ▼
  #fillable: array:6 [▶]
  #table: "Sample_table"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  +timestamps: true
  #connection: "mysql"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:20 [▶]
  #original: array:20 [▼
    "id" => "9"
    "firstName" => "test"
    "lastName" => "asdf"
    "middleName" => "test"
    "contactNo" => "2147483647"
    "emailAddress" => "test@gmail.com"
    "residenceAddress" => "afsf"
    "province_id" => "6"
    "city_id" => "3"
    "barangay_id" => "16982"
    "copyMailing" => null
    "mailingAddress" => null
    "mailing_province_id" => "6"
    "mailing_city_id" => "3"
    "mailing_barangay_id" => "16982"
    "status" => "0"
    "userIdentity" => "0"
    "global_id" => "0"
    "updated_at" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    "created_at" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
  ]
```

Comment: what  do you want actually

Comment: i just need the  #original: array:20 [▼ array

Comment: You want to get it via session if you do where do you want to get it in the controller or in the view?

Comment: i want to fetch it on view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `->getRawOriginal()`:

```php
Session::get('sample')[0]->getRawOriginal();
```